# missing @end + expected identifier "{" errors in XCode 4.2 .h module

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I can't get rid of two errors on my class module, even when I have simplified the code to the minimum expression:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@end
```

Both errors are reported on the @interface line, and they are:
- missing @end
- expected identifier or '{'

Comment: It seems like `NSObject` is undefined

Comment: Did you eventually resolve this problem? I'm seeing it now. Cleaning, deleting derived data . . . nothing is helping!

Comment: compiler can point you to completely wrong file. go trough all .h and .m files in your project and check for matching '@interface'/'@end', '@implementation'/'@end' and so on. it happens also if you by mistake import .m file instead of .h (it happens)

Comment: WTF? I still cannot resolve this problem and going crazy, such errors should not be in the ready product.

Comment: I forgot to add **@end** in one of my header file (.h file).

Answer (score 34):

Check the header files that are #imported on the same page, and verify that the headers have matching @interface/@end statements.

I had the same problem, and XCode reported that my .m file's @implementation had a missing @end statement, even when I pared it down to just:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "MyBadHeaderFile.h"
@implementation MasterViewController
@end
```

In reality the bug was a missing @end from a #imported MyBadHeaderFile.h file.

Comment: Thought I was going crazy, this was exactly my problem.  +1

Comment: exactly my problem as well except the error was landing in a completely unrelated file that was not modified and had zero imports other than UIKit. thanks to git i was able to simply browse through the files that had been modified and narrow it down to where it was missing from...

Comment: I forgot to add **@end** in one of my header file (.h file).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem found adding a `}` in my code got rid of the errors for me.

Before I added the `}` I was getting the following errors:

1. unexpected `@` in program (parse issue)
2. Expected `}` (parse issue)
3. `@end` is missing in implementation context (semantic issue)

Answer (score 4):

rokjarc's comment should be a correct answer:

1) compiler can point you to completely wrong file. go trough all .h and .m files in your project and check for matching '@interface'/'@end', '@implementation'/'@end' and so on.

2) it happens also if you by mistake import .m file instead of .h

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt matter in which file the error is appearing. Make sure to check for all the files you have recently modified. I appeared to have copied a file from test project to my actual project and forgot @end in one of the files. It gave me error on totally unrelated .h file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the implementation file of this class from "Compile sources in project settings"

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject{

}

@end
```

Comment: The curly brackets are not actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, the code was fine but it was throwing this error.

I eventually resolved it by cleaning the project, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

### PEBKAC + Lack of Specificity in the Static Analyzer Strings

#### The existing answers are *certainly* useful. I just want to add a common PEBKAC that causes this; as well as highlight that CLANG should be clearer here. Someone with domain knowledge should file a patch to make the error message clearer. The `\n@end\n` part of the message is ridiculous no matter what.

> (Showing line breaks as **\n** in a message designed to help users of a
>   GUI? *Really* CLANG?)

### The Cause

When you have just created a new Class, the `@interface` & `@implementation` files look extremely similar, and Xcode will automatically place your cursor in the implementation.

If you thoughtlessly begin typing out your interface (your method signature declarations) in the implementation file, you'll end up with this warning because the analyzer sees methods without opening and closing braces.

### A visual example, shown forthwith

[image: Missing @end is a case of PEBKAC]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error ,and it was because i had

```
@interface MyViewController ()
```

declared two times in the MyViewController.m